# Add a field from one array to another based on value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
$array1 = array
            (
                '3' => "Spinach dipped in mildly spiced batter & deep frie 3",
                '4' => "Spiced Potato Patties 4",
                '7' => "vegetable somasa 7 2nd add"
            );
$array2 = array
        (
            '0' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 3,
                    'image' => "Spinach_Pakora-small.jpg"
                ),

            '1' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 4,
                    'image' => "Aloo_Tikki-small.jpg"
                ),

            '2' => Array
                (
                    'id' => 7,
                    'image' => "Vegetable-Samosa-large.jpg"

                )
        )   ;
```

Final array will be

```
$final = array
(
    '0' => Array
        (
            'id' => 3,
            'image' => "Spinach_Pakora-small.jpg",
            'desc' => "Spinach dipped in mildly spiced batter & deep frie 3"
        ),

    '1' => Array
        (
            'id' => 4,
            'image' => "Aloo_Tikki-small.jpg",
            'desc' => "Spinach dipped in mildly spiced batter & deep frie 3"

        ),

    '2' => Array
        (
            'id' => 7,
            'image' => "Vegetable-Samosa-large.jpg",
            'desc' => "Spinach dipped in mildly spiced batter & deep frie 3"
        )

);
```

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This is pretty trivial using a `foreach` loop, and `isset` to see if an item exists under the id key in array1.